# how to bulid encapsulated structure with "push"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

I'm creating a structure that should look like this:

```
structure: [
{ name: "First Name", field: "first", width: "84px" },
{ name: "Last Name", field: "last", width: "84px" },
{ name: "2B", field: "total2B", width: "60px" },
{ name: "3B", field: "total3B", width: "60px" },
{ name: "HR", field: "totalHR", width: "60px" }
```

with this code:

```
var _gridStructure = [];
_gridStructure.push({
                field : metricNames[i],
                name : metricNames[i].replace("ANZAHL_", ""),
                styles : _gridStyle,
            });
```

It works fine. But now I need a structure like this:

```
structure: [
[
{ name: "First Name", field: "first", width: "84px", rowSpan: 2 },
{ name: "BB", field: "totalBB", width: "60px" },
{ name: "K", field: "totalK", width: "60px" }
],[
{ name: "Games as Batter", field: "totalGAB", colSpan: 2 },
{ name: "H", field: "totalH" },
{ name: "2B", field: "total2B" },
{ name: "3B", field: "total3B" },
{ name: "HR", field: "totalHR" }
]
```

How can I realise this with the "push"-function?

_gridStructure.push[0].push().... somethink like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_gridStructure[0].push()` would work for this.

EDIT: Provided that you initialize `_gridStructure` first. So:

```
_gridStructure = _gridStructure || [];
_gridStructure.push([]);
_gridStructure[0].push({your: "data"});
```

End result is equivalent to:

```
_gridStructure = [
  [{your: "data"}]
]
```